# on keyup, know the element of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do the next thing for the two ids: `targetingInput`, `excludeInput`:

when keyup, I want to get the value.

if the keyup is in targetingInput, get the value of targetingInput,

if the keyup is in excludeInput, get the value of excludeInput.

in the next example, I deal with the first case..

```
$('#targetingInput', '#excludeInput').live('keyup', function(e) {

    var value = document.getElementById('targetingInput').value;
}
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: `var value = this.value;` Beware, `live` is `dead` as for jq 1.9+

Comment: BTW, your selector is wrong, must be: `$('#targetingInput, #excludeInput')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/fully-understanding-the-codethiscode-keyword--net-21117)

```
$('#targetingInput, #excludeInput').live('keyup', function(e) {
    var value = this.value;
               //^ current element with event keyup 
}
```

---

Commented by [alexp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042216/alexp)

As of jQuery 1.9, the .live() method is eliminated. Use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers

Comment: you just need to write: $('#targetingInput, #excludeInput') instead what you wrote and it works :] thank you!

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, the .live() method is eliminated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: @alexP Added your worth comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
var value=this.value;
```

or

```
var value=$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `e.currentTarget`. See https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/

For example:

```
$('#targetingInput', '#excludeInput').live('keyup', function(e) {
    var value = e.currentTarget.value;
});
```

You shouldn't need to use `$(e.currentTarget).value`, as value is a native property and not a jQuery one. You could also use `this.value` as shown in some of the other answers, but that wouldn't work if you're binding `this` to some other object.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the event `e` to your callback. `e.currentTarget` will be the element triggering the event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget.

Knowing this, `$(e.currentTarget).val();` would return the value of the element triggering the `keyup` event.